# Is there a standard hotkey list somewhere

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, standards

There are numerous key combinations that can be considered as being part of an unofficial (as far as I know) standard. But is there a list of such combinations somewhere? Some examples:

```
F1 - Help
F3 - Show next match (when searching with Ctrl + F)
F5 - Refresh
Ctrl + Tab - Switch tab
Ctrl + Number - Choose tab
Ctrl + F - Find
Ctrl + P - Print
Ctrl + Left/Right arrow - switch to next space or delimiter when in text edit mode

etc...
```

Comment: Remember that standards can vary by locale. In US English `Ctrl+B` is a standard **B**old shortcut in tools like Microsoft Word, however in French for instance it's mapped to `Ctrl+G` for _caractère **G**ras_...

Comment: ... and `Ctrl+Shift+F` in German for ***F**ett* (so not even the same number keys).

Answer (score 1):

This article might help.

[47 Keyboard Shortcuts That Work in All Web Browsers](http://www.howtogeek.com/114518/47-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-in-all-web-browsers/)

Answer (score 1):

There's not any official standard I know of. The following link looks pretty comprehensive as far as listing existing applications.

http://allhotkeys.com/

Shortcuts really depend on the software application you are developing... Windows, Unix, browser, etc...